# print() с частью текста и форматированием как переменная Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Есть повторяющаяся функция `print('\n' + f'{"  ЗАПУСКАЕМ ТЕСТ  ":=^120}' + '\n')`

на выходе получаем
чтото типа

================  ЗАПУСКАЕМ ТЕСТ  ================

или с другим текстом

=================  КОНЕЦ ТЕСТА  ==================

Текст внутри может меняться, форматирование - нет.

Как обернуть `print('\n' + f'{"":=^120}' + '\n')` в переменную, с возможностью подставлять нужный текст, типа `print_var('ПРИМЕР ТЕКСТА')`?

Comment: Наведите пример вызова этой функции, а то не совсем ясно, что Вы хотите

Comment: конкретизируйте, нужно больше примеров

Comment: В самом начале же `print('\n' + f'{"  ЗАПУСКАЕМ ТЕСТ  ":=^120}' + '\n')` просто хочу уменьшить количество одинаковых вызовов с разным текстом.

Comment: @extrn по-моему ваше решение отвечает на заданный вопрос, возобновите это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def print_var(str):
    print(f'\n{" " + str + " ":=^120}\n')
```

В результате:

```
>>> print_var('КАКОЙ_ТО ТЕКСТ')
===================================================== КАКОЙ_ТО ТЕКСТ =====================================================
```

Comment: Спасибо, решение подошло. Похоже я слишком устал, раз сам очевидное не увидел)))

Comment: @ИльяДмитриев, ну бывает. Стоит отойти на несколько минут от дела, как сразу что-то в голову придет:)

Answer (score 0):

`print('\n' + f'{  string  :=^120}' + '\n')`

`string` - переменная, в которой хранится нужный текст